# What is an alternative for tar (compressor)?

Tags: linux, file-compression

I have a 200MB file. I want to compress this into a small file. Now I'm using TAR. but it only compresses word-like files, not binary files. So, I'm searching an alternative tool for tar to compress the binary which is also more efficient.

Comment: Your request is not clear to me. `tar` doesn't compress at all `.tar` file is just an uncompressed container, its `gzip` or `bzip` that compresses a tar --> `.tar.gz`. `gzip` will surely compress binaries. But if the binary file is already compressed (`jpg` files or alike) then no compression method will be of much help. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

[p7zip](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/p7zip) is the Unix/Linux port of [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), a freeware and open source archiver which supports different compression methods through their own [7z format](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html).

Of course, there's a practical limit to how efficient compression methods can be (for arbitrary files), but it's probably worth giving a try.